# How to throw a ClassCastException when a Double variable is cast to the generic type T?

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I'm implementing a generics class `LabelEncoder<T>` in Java, referring to `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`.


Besides providing the method `void fit(T[] labels, boolean natural)`, this class also provides another method `void fit(double[] labels, boolean natural)`, which is more frequently used than `void fit(Double[] labels, boolean natural`. It's expected that this method will throw a ClassCastException if `T` is not `Double`. But to my surprise, nothing happened when testing.


Here is my code below:

```
/**
 * Encodes target labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.
 * If T is comparable, this class supports encoding by "natural-order" or by "index-order".
 * Otherwise, this class only supports encoding by "index-order".
 *
 * @param <T> the Java Class of labels
 * @author Cloudy1225
 */
public class LabelEncoder <T> extends Encoder<T>{

    /**
     * Holds the mapping between labels and encodings.
     */
    public Map<T, Double> encodingMap;

    /**
     * Whether this encoder has already been fitted.
     */
    private boolean fitted;


    /**
     * Creates a LabelEncoder.
     */
    public LabelEncoder() {}

    /**
     * Fits the label encoder by "natural-order" or by "index-order".
     *
     * @param labels a double array of target values.
     * @param natural true: encode by "natural-order"; false: encode by "index-order"
     * @throws ClassCastException if the generic type of this class is not Double
     */
    public void fit(double[] labels, boolean natural) {
        this.reset(natural);
        Double encoding = 0.0;
        for (Double label: labels) {
************T l = (T) label;************
            Double oldValue = this.encodingMap.put(l, encoding);
            if (oldValue == null) { // It denotes that the label hadn't been in the map.
                encoding++;
            }
        }
        this.fitted = true;
    }

     /**
     * Fits the label encoder by "natural-order" or by "index-order".
     * If given labels are not comparable, "natural" will be automatically set false.
     *
     * @param labels an array of target values.
     * @param natural true: encode by "natural-order"; false: encode by "index-order"
     */
    public void fit(T[] labels, boolean natural) {
        if (!(labels instanceof Comparable[])) {
            natural = false;
        }
        this.reset(natural);
        Double encoding = 0.0;
        for (T label: labels) {
            Double oldValue = this.encodingMap.put(label, encoding);
            if (oldValue == null) { 
                encoding++;
            }
        }
        this.fitted = true;
    }

     /**
     * Resets or initializes before being fitted.
     *
     * @param natural true: encode by "natural-order"; false: encode by "index-order"
     */
    private void reset(boolean natural) {
        // Sorting is implemented by TreeMap or by LinkedHashMap.
        if (natural) {
            this.encodingMap = new TreeMap<T, Double>();
        } else {
            this.encodingMap = new LinkedHashMap<T, Double>();
        }
        this.fitted = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelEncoder<String> encoder = new LabelEncoder<>();
        encoder.fit(new double[] {3,4,5}); // It's expected that a ClassCastException will be thrown here.
        Map<String, Double> map = encoder.encodingMap;
        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

The test result is as follows:

```
{3.0=0.0, 4.0=1.0, 5.0=2.0}
```

So how to throw a ClassCastException when executing `T l = (T) label;` ?


Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't, because generics aren't reified at runtime (their type information gets reduced (usually to `Object`) at runtime). Either take in a `Class<T>` in your constructor and use `clazz.cast()` or rewrite your code to remove all unchecked cast (and raw type) warnings.

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be a real advantage in providing the `double[]` overload, as it’s doing exactly the same as the generic code, including all overhead of boxing operations. And what’s the point of this `Double encoding;`  holding an ascending number? If all you’re doing, is `++`, why don’t you use an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing `new double[] {3,4,5}` you are doing an implicit casting to double, so you are actually passing an array of double to the method, thus you can't expect a ClassCastException.
Furthermore you can't expect an Exception from a casting to generic, is a perfectly legitimate casting.
If you want to throw an exception you should try something like:

```
if(!(label instanceof Double))
    throw new Exception("Not a Double");
```

Please provide further detail on what you are trying to achieve, because is not clear to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean, `void fit(double[] labels, boolean natural)` only can be used in `LabelEncoder<Double>`. For `<LabelEncoder<String>`, it will throw a ClassCastException. Of couse, `void fit(Double[] labels, boolean natural)` is enough for  `LabelEncoder<Double>`. But I want `LabelEncoder<Double>` can support `double[]`.